# Prolog: Finding all unary predicates P_1 that hold true for some term T

Tags: prolog

I have some facts like:

```
person(david).

student(david).
```

I need to find the functors that `david` is in. So I need to post a query like:

```
some_query(david)
```

and I need the answers to be
`person` and 
`student`.

How can I do this in Prolog? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible without resorting to some special predicates provided by the interpreter, i.e., this is not pure Prolog anymore, but for swi-prolog this works:

```
findFor(Const, X) :-
    current_predicate(X, Z),
    not(predicate_property(Z, built_in)),
    Z =.. [_, _],
    Y =.. [X, Const],
    call(Y).
```

then just call: `findFor(david, X)`, or if you want all answers in one query use `findAll`.

Comment: s(X): IMO your code could get even better by taking the following suggestions into account: (1) use `call/2` instead of `(=..)/2` and `call/1`. (2) use `functor/3` for getting/checking the arities of compounds and atoms, not `(=..)/2`. (3) use `(\+)/1` instead of `not/1`. HTH

Comment: Also, use the standard `current_predicate/1` predicate, not `current_predicate/2`.